# How do I add and remove components? (Parallax JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, parallax.js

In Parallax JS:

I have a menu that will change what is being 'parallaxed', I do not know how to change the components within the `<li>` tags. I think I need to stop the plugin and then start it again but cannot find the destroy command.

I am using the JQuery version.

Thank yooou

The link to the GitHub:
https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax
^components to this!

Edit. I had to retype this as for some reason it lost the important but which was that I wanted to add/remove components to Parallax JS

Comment: Read up on JavaScript/jQuery then. There are many many functions that change HTML elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing the DOM elements within the scene this simple line will update the whole arrangement rather nicely:

```
$('#scene').parallax().parallax('updateLayers');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove HTML elements using JavaScript/jQuery. An example of removing one would would look like this,

```
$("#foo").remove();
```

This will get the HTML element that has an id of foo, then remove the element entirely.

And to add an element you can get the parent element of the element you want and call append,

```
$("#outerFoo").append('<div id="foo"></div>');
```

Comment: This is almost there, I have jus' figured it out tho'. Avail!x